# Graphics bugs on google spread Sheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, microsoft-edge

My google spread sheet started to look like this (pic), looks like it just happenig on Microsoft edge and it only dissapears when i close and open a new tab.

[Google_SS_Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIV2Q.jpg)

It is not edited, it turns worse when i scroll.

Comment: Which version of the Edge browser you are using? I try to test the issue on the **MS Edge Version 88.0.705.50** and found that Google spreadsheets work fine. Please see my test result [here](https://imgur.com/a/RPOlayt). If you are using an older version of the Edge browser then try to test the issue with the latest stable version. For testing purposes, try to disable the **Use hardware acceleration when available** option under `edge://settings/system`. See whether it helps to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like hardware acceleration was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: From the previous comment, it looks like your issue is solved by disabling the **Use hardware acceleration when available** option. I suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an accepted answer for this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test the issue on the **MS Edge Version 88.0.705.50** and found that Google spreadsheets work fine.

Please see my test result here.

[image]

If you are using an older version of the Edge browser then try to test the issue with the latest stable version.

For testing purposes, try to **disable** the **Use hardware acceleration when available** option under `edge://settings/system`. See whether it helps to fix this issue.